# convert datetime string to datetime

Tags: python, mysql, string, datetime

I know questions like these get asked all the time, but my specific problem doesn't seem to come up (at least I can't find it).

So my problem is like this. I have a MySQL database which has lots of data in it, with one column being full of dates. When I pull these dates, I automatically store them into a list which works great.

But, I also have to format the dates to calculate with. For instance, if I work on one of the dates I may need to extract just the month number. Having imported datetime, I would have imagined it was simple with strftime, but it wasn't. The problem is that they are stored in a string format (list is called last_shipped).

The dates come into the list according to this format:

```
((datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 30, 0, 0),),)
```

So when I try and use strftime I get the error

```
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'
```

My question is, how do I convert a list full of these to a list of workable datetime objects?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I am using MySQLdb.
An example of the code I have tried that produces the error above is:

```
z = datetime.datetime.strftime(gr, '%m')
```

In this case z is the datetime string I mentioned above.

Comment: "So when I try and use strftime". Show us what you tried, please

Comment: `strftime` is for *creating* strings; you want `strptime` to *parse* strings (and create datetime objects from the strings).

Comment: Are you using python's `MySQLdb`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime?rq=1

Comment: Are you storing the dates in a text field or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you:

[`time.strptime(string[, format])`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime)

> Parse a string representing a time according to a format. The return value is a struct_time as returned by gmtime() or localtime().

[`time.strftime(format[, t])`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime)

> Convert a tuple or struct_time representing a time as returned by gmtime() or localtime() to a string as specified by the format argument.

Comment: I've just used strptime and works a treat. Thanks for saving my early baldness. Can't believe I missed it, the price for being a newbie